# set up puppet master to listen on 2 ports

Tags: puppet

We have set up puppet master to listen on regular 8140, but some reasons we have to run it on 443 **as well** as 8140

So, yeah, 2 ports

Is that at all possible and where should we look?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your puppet master is running on Linux, you can do this with some [configuration of iptables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/) to forward one port to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Apache+Passenger stack you can modify the puppetmaster VHost to :

```
<VirtualHost *:8140 *:443>
  [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to remove the default VHost listening on 443 without unloading the SSL module.

If you're using webrick, your only choice is to redirect 443 to 8140.